# Why does the code appear in ALL white now? It used to be color coded now there is no distinguishment between functions, comments etc

Tags: pine-script

I code indicators on Tradingview, the code used to be color coded. Now it appears all in white, or black depending on the theme youre using. It was extremely helpful to have functions, built in variables, etc each have their own color. Now it seems that feature has disappeared.....

Comment: It is still there for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do check your extensions, you might have installed a theme extension that overrides that